# socket.io referring to localhost despite being set as a specfic IP

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to use web sockets to connect from a Google Chrome browser on my phone to a server running node.js and socket.io.

Using the remote debugging tool in Google Chrome I get this error in the console

```
Failed to load resource http://localhost/socket.io/1/?t=1368744562638
```

This happens despite me specifying my internal LAN IP in code for the client like so:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.3');
```

Furthermore it seems like the first heartbeat request makes it but starts to fail after that.

[image: The client requests] 
The code runs as expected when running the client on the server.

Comment: It has been brought to my attention that the image does not zoom. So sorry about that :) I'll rehost it somewhere else if requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am of course a idiot. I had another javascript file that had not been updated to connect to the specific IP I had set and was still set to "localhost".

After updating the host that socket.io should connect to in that javascript file everything is now running smoothly :)